# Can't run Composer on my Mac Mountain Lion - openssl extension

Tags: macos, https, openssl, composer-php

I installed several CMS that require Composer.

Since 2 days i got error and can't go on.

```
[RuntimeException] You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

I check the following:

```
$ openssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
$ which openssl /opt/local/bin/openssl
```

phpinfo say Phar - Native OpenSSL support enabled and OpenSSL support enabled.

Still if i do

```
$ php -info| grep openssl OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)
```

Does someone has a clue about what i should do to be able to run Composer ?

Comment: Any installed openssl on your machine does not mean much. PHP needs its own openssl extension.

Comment: ok Sven. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You'd have to install the php openssl extension. I believe this could be as easy as in this description: http://www.ifusio.com/blog/install-open-ssl-extension-for-php-on-mac-osx - but your setup might be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In doubt (tks to Sven for pushing me that direction ;) ), I reinstall using port the openssl extension.

```
sudo port install php5-openssl
```

It didn't download files but reset something in the preferences and i was able to run Composer install properly on Tiki Wiki CMS (the CMS i'm using most).

Comment: Had to change this to: sudo port install php55-openssl since I have php5.5 on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

which version you install is also important. there is a bug in openssl 0.9.8.
read more here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2021