# How to fix "could not open socket in Zend Mail (Zend Framework 2)

Tags: php

Please help me fix problem on Mac OS, when I type on my windows, It works.
I try on my mac, it shows "could not open socket".
Everybody could help me.

```
public function indexAction(){
    $mail = new Mail\Message;
                $mail->setFrom('paradise.losebaby@gmail.com','Flyoverfly Training');
                $mail->addTo('thanhbvh@yahoo.com.vn','maithanh');
                $mail->setSubject('Xác nhận việc phục hồi mật khẩu');
                $mail->setBody('maithanh');

                $transport = new SmtpTransport;
                $option = new SmtpOptions(array(
                    'name' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'port' => 465,
                    'connection_class' => 'login',
                    'connection_config' => array(
                        'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
                        'password' => 'mypass',
                        'ssl' => 'ssl'
                    )
                ));
                $transport->setOptions($option);
                $transport->send($mail);
    return new ViewModel;
}
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 7):

May be a firewall issue. However I'm pretty sure php-openssl doesn't installed/enabled on your OS. Under the hood Zend will call stream_socket_client() in order to connect to remote server.
As sending email through gmail requires security layer (SSL/TLS), stream_socket_client() will require open ssl support (ssl://).
So you must have ssl support on OS, check:

[image]
Or getting the list of supported socket transports:

[image]

And here goes some useful links:

- [Roll your own PHP to support OpenSSL instead of Secure Transport (Mac)](http://www.farces.com/wikis/naked-server/php/php-openssl/)
- [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x)
- [Important note for curl users on OS X Mavericks 10.9](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html)
- [fsockopen() (go to hostname option for details)](http://php.net/fsockopen)
- [Can't run Composer on my Mac Mountain Lion - openssl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137408/cant-run-composer-on-my-mac-mountain-lion-openssl-extension)
- [OpenSSL support in PHP under MAMP](http://jaspan.com/openssl-support-php-under-mamp)
- [OpenSSL Version MacOSX Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/openssl-version-macosx-homebrew/15234017)
- [Building OpenSSL on your Mac (MacOS X)](http://Building%20OpenSSL%20on%20your%20Mac%20(MacOS%20X))
- [Zend Mail Abastract Protocol (stream_socket_client under the hoods)](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendMail/blob/master/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php#L203)
- [stream_socket_client()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)
- [OpenSSL installation](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)
- [Net Transports](http://php.net/manual/en/transports.inet.php)
- [stream_get_transports()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-transports.php)