# Could not open socket in zend

Tags: email, zend-framework, procedure

I have am using an SMTP mail server. When I register a new user, I recieve the following error message:

```
An error occurred
Could not open socket
Additional information:
Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
C:\wamp\www\zendtest\vendor\zendframework\zend-mail\src\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php:209
Message:
Could not open socket
```

#### Code

```php
<?php
return array(
    'mail' => array(
        'transport' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'connection_class' => 'login',
                'port' => '465',
                'connection_config' => array(
                    'username' => 'varinderkumar.dx@gmail.com',
                    'password' => '********',
                    'ssl' => 'ssl'
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
);
?>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "could not open socket in Zend Mail (Zend Framework 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433816/how-to-fix-could-not-open-socket-in-zend-mail-zend-framework-2)

Comment: You can delete your comment above, I included your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

go to `wamp->php->php.ini` open this file and find `ssl.dll` after that remove `;` symbol from starting of line. then save the file and restart the wamp. This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For cPanel: Try disabling WHM >> Secuirty >> SMTP Restrictions.