# How to fix error with OpenSSL protocol Composer?

Tags: php, macos, ssl, composer-php, macos-sierra

I tried to install composer like:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

It returns me an error:

`The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl` despite on the extension OpenSSL is enabled in PHP.

I can see that in `phpinfo()`:

`PHP Version 5.6.30`

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version LibreSSL 2.2.7
OpenSSL Header Version  LibreSSL 2.2.7
Openssl default config  /private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable ssl verification by adding -k.

```
curl -ksS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: The same error: `Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl`

Comment: Which phpinfo is that you posted? cli? fpm? mod_php? Openssl must be enabled in `cli`.

Comment: Can you explain how to enable with cli?

Comment: I use MAMP Web Server, Mac OS Sierra

Comment: If you run this code from mac console/shell, it means php cli executes it. Can you also run this in the console and share the output `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep "openssl"`

Comment: I get this: `OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)`

Comment: Lookse like openssl is not properly installed or configured. Check this post for the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137408/cant-run-composer-on-my-mac-mountain-lion-openssl-extension

Comment: But `phpinfo` tells that it is enabled

Comment: The phpinfo you are checking in the browser, is not the one for `cli` package. It is for your web server.

Comment: I tried this, I have 7 version PHP, not 5. Also I get error: `sudo: port: command not found`

Comment: Can you run `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini` to find the php.ini path, and then check that file for openssl extension if it is active etc..

Comment: It gives me `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib` what next?

Comment: Here there is not extension openssl

Comment: There has to be a `php.ini` file there, did you find it ?

Comment: turning off SSL does not fix the issue, as even if you get that to work, when you try to install composer packages you'll need SSL to work or you will continue to have errors